# Laravel authentication using mobile number

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.5

I'm currently using Laravel 5.5, as you know Laravel by default offers authentication by email, but in my case I want to change its behaviour and allow the user to login using the mobile number. so Where would I have to do the modifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#included-authenticating):

> By default, Laravel uses the email field for authentication. If you would like to customize this, you may define a username method on your `LoginController`:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'mobile_number';
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#included-authenticating

Answer (score 3):

LoginController

```
public function username()
{
    return 'mobile';
}
```

also can validate

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}
```